# Looking for a bitmap editor for screenshots

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot, image-processing, image-editor, scrot-command

I've started using `scrot` for screenshots; this works beautifully, but occasionally I need to edit screenshots to

- blur personal information
- add text
- add arrows
- add a box around something

I'm looking for a lightweight bitmap editor that will launch quickly from the command line (so that I can use it with `scrot --exec`), and will allow me to add blurring, text, arrows and boxes with a minimal number of keystrokes, mousing. Ideally, I'd like a keyboard shortcut, then select area for any given action.

Does anyone know of such a beast?

---

Edit: I don't consider Gimp to be lightweight: it launches slowly, drawing shapes involves a two step process -- *select area / stroke selection* -- the second of which doesn't seem to have a shortcut key... I'm looking for a tool that I can use to make edits in a couple of seconds, and save.

Comment: I use Pinta for that.

Comment: Technically you can launch any application from the terminal but I don't know what you would think of as "lightweight".

Comment: Which tools have you already tried? How about http://shutter-project.org/ , it's in Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use gimp, but Lubuntu comes with **mtpaint**, which is much lighter than gimp. You find it in the repository 'universe'. Try it and check if it will work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GIMP is a very powerful image editor that can do just about anything if you have the know-how and skill. You can download it here: [www.gimp.org/downloads/](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)
And if you go here: http://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-photo-editor you can view a much longer list of opensource editors.